# Remove custom post type in url?

Tags: custom-post-types

I created a custom post type Track and I want the posts url to be exactly like a normal post url. Now it adds an extra "track" in the url ex: www.site.com/track/title. I want www.site.com/title. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a custom rewrite rule in functions.php:

```
function your_cpt_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('(.*?)$', 'index.php?your_cpt=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('after_theme_setup', 'your_cpt_rewrite_rule');
```

Comment: Your regex is wrong (no leading `^`), and this is a terrible idea. You're going to prevent WordPress from matching any other things with this. In other words, this will probably 404 every page -- except for the rare instances where `.*?` actually matches a custom post type's slug.